# How to draw a line with Bresenham's algorithm in haskell

Tags: haskell, bresenham

I found codes in Haskell wiki of "Bresenham's line drawing algorithm", however, I cannot easily understand the part of the beginning, so I rewrote it. But I cannot draw the lines when the slope is over 1/2.
Here is part of my codes.

```
line :: Point -> Point -> [Point]
line (x0,y0) (x1,y1)
| abs (y1-y0) > abs(x1-x0)  = line (y0,x0) (y1,x1)
| x0 > x1                   = line (x1,y1) (x0,y0)
| otherwise                 = plotLine x0 y0 0
  where
```

And in where clause, I define the plotLine function just like the "go" in Haskell wiki. Since the rest of my codes are almost the same as the codes in Haskell wiki, so I think the problem is from the beginning. But I cannot figure it out. Can anyone help me?

By the way, here is the website of "Bresenham's line drawing algorithm" on Haskell wiki: https://wiki.haskell.org/Bresenham%27s_line_drawing_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are missing is the `maySwitch` function. Bresenham's Algorithm works only on lines with slopes between 0 and 1 (i.e. 45 degrees). For steeper lines you need to swap the x and y coordinates on both the input and output. This is what the `maySwitch` function does. You have only swapped them on the input.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I forgot to switch them on the outout.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it seems like that you were missing the `maySwitch` function, just like Paul pointed it out. Kinda "shameless plug" but let me include an implementation of mine that I wrote two years ago when I was trying to improve my Haskell skills: https://github.com/Lucsanszky/soft-engine/commit/801e802f498bb9c19528cd074f169bc15cbd5191#diff-59f6fe8726905567287c68be078212a0R66

Hopefully, by seeing an alternative implementation in a slightly different context, you will have a better understanding of the algorithm.